# IgniteUI combo box datasource updates with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, infragistics

I have created a igComboBox with it's datasource set as an observableArray. When I add items to the array, I would like the datasource of the combobox to automatically pull in the new values, without having to set the self.datasource:sourceListArray() explicitly. How can I achieve this?

```
    self.sourceListArray = ko.observableArray();

    $("#dataSource").igCombo({
        allowCustomValue: false,
        showDropDownButton: true,
        enableClearButton: false,
        dataSource: self.sourceListArray(),
        nullText: "Select Data Source",
        selectionChanged: self.dataSourceChanged
    });

    function PopulateSourceList(sourceList) {

        for (var i = 0; i < sourceList.length; i++) {
            self.sourceListArray.push(sourceList[i].ServiceName);
        }
        $("#dataSource").igCombo({ dataSource: self.sourceListArray() }); //don't want this
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current sample is not really using the [Knockout support for the Ignite UI Combo](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/jQuery/2013.2/CLR4.0/?page=igCombo_KnockoutJS_Support.html). Have a look at this sample for [KnockoutJS Binding](http://www.igniteui.com/combo/bind-combo-with-ko), by comparison you are initializing the Combo the default way, not going through the Knockout binding process (where our handler kicks in). The solution is simple - define the combo like this:

```
<div id="dataSource" data-bind="igCombo: { 
                allowCustomValue: false,
                showDropDownButton: true,
                enableClearButton: false,
                dataSource: self.sourceListArray(),
                nullText: 'Select Data Source',
                selectionChanged: self.dataSourceChanged
              }"></div>
```

And then everything will just work - http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/athF2/